# Fresh XP +click once +cannot connect

Tags: wcf, clickonce

Greetings, 
we have to following problem. 
Our application is deployed using ClickOnce. Everything is running fine and application is able to connect to the wcf service. The problem occurs when application is installed on FRESH XP machine without .net Framework and Windows Installater (that were selected in ClickOnce prerequities). 
Application downloads .NET Framework 3.5SP1 and windows installer but then it cannot connect the the server. Reboot after install does not help. 
The strange is that this application has been installed on 10 xp machines and 4 of them can connect to the service without a problem

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this and were forced to reinstall .net on some machines no idea why though.

---

This is a shot in the dark but have you tried depends.exe and see if it can profile what is happening.

Also Take a look at [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/) and get a crash dump and see if you can use it to at least tell you what is complaining the loudest.

Comment: Then you have a deeper issue.

Comment: I don;t know what the error is as I client did not send the error yet

Answer (score 0):

Are there any dlls referenced in your application? You might want to check them (Under project's Properties\Publish tab\Application Files button) see if you missed to include the needed dlls or files.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e8ff221e20.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e8ff221e20.jpg)

Comment: well, i think this not cause the problem because on some machines it works fine.

Comment: @niao - It will work fine to the other machine if it already has the needed files\assemblies installed there. Do you use third-party objects?

Comment: wpf toolkit only. But how can it be possible that on some machines it works fine? ALL these xp are fresh! BTW I have all required files

Comment: @niao - We have encountered here a instance wherein the application doesn't function accordingly because of wpf toolkit. The reason was the pc used for development has the wpf toolkit installed on different path compared to the target machine's. Maybe you could check that out also.

Comment: wpf toolkit was not installed previously on that machine. It was installed during app installation

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say 'cannot connect to the server'?

a. The machine cannot connect to the install location and therefore the clickone app is not installed?

b. The app installs (along with the pre-requisites) and starts fine. Then it is unable to connect/communicate with your WCF services.

I presume (b) I just wanted to clarify.

What happens when you ping the machine the services are on from one of the failed install machines? Also what happens when you put the service url into a browser on one of the failed install machines? Can you see the wsdl?

Obviously your deployment package works because it works on those other machines (I assume it IS the same package all machines are installing?), therefore I doubt you are missing any dll's as a ClickOnce app should include all dll's it needs (sometimes you do need to tell ClickOnce explicitly to include).

Last question is, when the app tries to call the service, exactly what exception is it getting back?

I just remembered something which has caught me out in the past with some machines being unable to connect but others can...especially 'new' machines.

Check this file:- C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Check the contents on a machine that works and one that doesn't. We have some IP to machine name mapping going on that on new machines is not set and so the new machines cannot find the servers.

Comment: as you wrote, The app installs and starts fine. I just can't connect to the server. The exception is not thrown, instead I get a null response. (which is of type WCFResponse in my case). I can see the wsdl from that machine.

Comment: and the call definately isn't hitting the service and being rejected for some reason?
Are you connected using https? Is it perhaps a certificate related issue??

Comment: no..it not using https and I also don't use certificates in this particular case.